# Monthly average without aggregating on monthly level

Tags: sql, presto

The table below is aggregating  `order_value`
using data from the last 6 month, without creating an additional subquery I would like to calculate the monthly average of all orders over the last 6 month (see desired output table below).

Table

```
customer_id | order_timestamp      | order_value
A             2020-01-01 10:30:51    100
```

Desired output table

```
customer_id  | sum_orders |  monthly_avg_orders
A              100.000       16.666
```

This is what I already have

```
select
   customer_id, 
   sum(order_value)

from table

group by customer_id
```

Comment: Why not `sum(order_value) AS sum_orders`, `AVG(order_value) AS avg_orders_last_6_month`??

Comment: but this would give you the average of all orders not monthly average

Comment: The example doesn't make sense to me. The average is one ninth of the only value of an order. I'm unclear on what you want.

Comment: sorry just changed the example

Comment: Do you just want sum(order_value)/6?

Comment: Add more data to your table and desired output as well to better explain your need... Because avg for each month for 6 months would give 6 rows right??

Comment: exactly but without hard coding it so ideally something dynamic

Comment: So please show a result example that has 6 rows and provide some source data that would generate the result